# Changing UIBarButtonItem title impossible?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, title, uibarbuttonitem

Silly thing, I am trying to change the title on a UIBarButtonItem if a certain condition in a for-loop is met. However I'm having trouble.

I've tried

```
self.barButtonItem.title=@"NewTitle"
```

and

```
[self.barButtonItem setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

I even did a setNeedsDisplay on the view afterwards without any luck. By the way, yes I am getting the old array of buttons from self.navigationBar.items, removing the old button, and setting the new one.

If I change the screen orientation (flip ipad), the button title does change. But otherwise, it stays the same.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

If u explore the documentation, apple says :

"You should set this property before adding the item to a bar."

For that reason,

```
cancel_btn.title = "something"  // It does not work !
```

Because u already set the item to the bar.

**Solution**

```
//
let theTitle = "something"

//
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: theTitle, style: 
UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: 
#selector(cancelAction))
```

Now u set the title before adding the item to the bar.

Answer (score 0):

I make use of the `possibleTitles` property of `UIBarButtonItem` for this.

Try this when you create the button:

```
self.barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...];
self.barButtonItem.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Title 1", @"Title 2", nil];
```

then later, to change the title, do:

```
self.barButtonItem.title = @"Title X"; // must be one of the possibleTitles
```

Comment: good suggestion, still same behavior - work with ipad flipped, otherwise  stays the same..

Comment: in viewDidLoad: self.visitButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Visit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(visitPlace)]; self.visitButton.possibleTitles=[NSSet setWithObjects:@"Visit", @"Unvisit", nil];
    NSMutableArray *buttons=[self.navigationBar.items mutableCopy];
    [buttons addObject:self.visitButton];
    
    self.navigationBar.items=buttons;

Comment: The `UIBarButtonItem` code is fine but the rest is all wrong. The `self.navigationBar.items` array is an array of `UINavigationItem`, not `UIBarButtonItem`. You want to adjust the buttons on `self.navigationItem`.

Comment: rmaddy, I don't think what you said is correct, because in Apple's own UISplitViewController delegate, they set a UIBarButtonItem via -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc; when I pad is put into portrait, and it works

Comment: Look at the docs for `UINavigationBar items]`. It's an array of `UINavigationItem`, not `UIBarButtonItem`. I have no idea how this is related to the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` method you just posted.

Comment: Because in that method you add and remove the barButtonItem to the self.navigationBar.items and it works (when the ipad is flipped). That's why I took that approach with my visit button

Comment: Huh? That split controller code does not touch the `navigationBar.items` property at all. If anything you play with the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems` (or similar) properties. Huge difference between `navigationItem` and `navigationBar`.

Comment: I have a UIToolBar at the top of the detail view controller (named navigationBar) so the buttons are getting added to that

Comment: Oh. Never mind. I thought you were talking about the standard navigationBar property of a UINavigationController. Sorry for the confusion.